# Line break in citation with organization as author

Tags: line-breaking, margins, citing, natbib

I have the following reference:

```
@MISC{EX2012,
  author = {{S}ingle {A}uthor {O}rganization},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Example}
}
```

A citation for this is breaking after "Author", but extending beyond the margin, as shown in the following example layout in the PDF:

```
Demo text demo text demo to margin
Demo text which cites it (Single Author
Organization, 2012) and flows over
the margin.
```

How can I solve this? I am using `natbib` and citing with `\citep{EX2012}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the `.bbl` file the entry becomes

```
\bibitem[{S}ingle~{A}uthor {O}rganization(2012)]{EX2012}
{S}ingle~{A}uthor {O}rganization.
\newblock Example, 2012.
```

(I'm assuming you use `natbib`). This is because BibTeX interprets the author as having two given names, precisely "Single Author" and a family name "Organization"; in these cases a tie is put between the given names.

There's no need to protect uppercase letters in the `author` field (which is instead necessary in the `title` field). In order to tell BibTeX that the author has only a "family name", enclose the name in additional braces:

```
@MISC{EX2012,
  author = {{Single Author Organization}},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Example}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Without some extra help, BibTeX and `natbib` cannot tell that you're dealing with a "corporate" author; instead, BibTeX thinks that you're dealing with an author who has two given names, viz., `Single` and `Author`, and one family name, `Organization`. As a result (see also @egreg's answer), the *optional argument* -- which is used when creating callouts via a command such as `\citep` -- of the `\bibitem` with key `EX2012` is formed as `{S}ingle~{A}uthor {O}rganization`, and LaTeX can't find a hyphenation point within the first, concatenated "word".

When dealing with a "corporate" author, it's recommended to encase the entire argument in an extra set of curly braces. Thus, you should write

```
author = {{Single Author Organization}},
```

This will ensure that BibTeX will treat this particular author correctly. This, in turn, will lead to a better setup of the optional argument of the associated `\bibitem`, letting LaTeX find more permissible break points within the words "Author", "Single", and "Organization".

Comment: The braces in the question have no influence on hyphenation; it's right to enclose the author in an additional pair of braces, but that's not the problem.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I'll rewrite the first paragraph

Comment: Thanks. I know you were first, but I'm going to accept egreg's answer.